# Analytic function to count each customer with many accounts only once

Tags: sql, netezza, analytic-functions

I'm having a slow day and for some reason am blanking on how to do this. Please help me. 
I have an Analytic function to count each customer with many accounts only once. Want a total of each distinct customer. I have to list the customers with their accounts. Many accounts for each customer

I'm using functions like this. 
COUNT(1) OVER(partition by cust.SK_CUST_RM_ID) total_cnt1

I'm looking for this output

```
cust account  distinc_cust
 1     a           3
 1     b           3
 2     a           3
 2     b           3
 2     c           3
 3     a           3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Netezza supports `count(distinct)` as an analytic function.  So, you can use this trick:

```
select t.*,
       max(dr) over () as distinct_cust
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by cust) as dr
      from t
     ) t;
```

As an analytic functions, you would just use:

```
select t.*, count(distinct cust) over ()
from t;
```

Comment: It does, so how would I use count distinct?